# HTTP POST RETURNING BAD REQUEST ERROR 400 FROM ANDROID HTTPURLConnection

Tags: android, wcf, http, post

I am using the HTTPURLConnection class to connect my android application to my WCF web service. I am using Microsoft Network Monitor to trace the request and it hits my server as thus.

- Http: Request, POST /iEService/Service.svc/register_user

Command: POST
    URI: /iEService/Service.svc/register_user

```
Location: /iEService/Service.svc/register_user 
ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
UserAgent:  Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; A0001 Build/LRX22G)
Host:  win-server
Connection:  Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding:  gzip
ContentType:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
MediaType:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
ContentLength:  183
HeaderEnd: CRLF
payload: HttpContentType =  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Last_Name: l_one
 Birthday: bd_one
 Email: e_one
 Username: u_one
 Business_Location: bl_one
 Security_Answer: sa_one
 Security_Question: s_one
 First_Name: f_one
 Password: p_one
 IMEI_Number: imei_one
```

However, I get a Bad Request error 400. I cannot see anything wrong with the request. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my WCF service method. All i had to do was add
BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
to the method header.

And it worked.

Comment: I added this one, but im still getting file.notfound.exception when i try to POST, the GET is working fine

Comment: @user987760 make sure your method is set to post like this, Method:="POST"